# searching data between dates stored in varchar in mysql

Tags: mysql, date, compare, between

I am storing my dates in column server_date_time in `varchar` in `dd/mm/yyyy` format and i want to fetch the records lying between some dates so i have used the query

```
    select * from activity_emp 
where date_format(str_to_date(substr(server_date_time,1,10),'%d/%m/%Y'),'%d/%m/%Y')>=
'29/09/2012'
    and date_format(str_to_date(substr(server_date_time,1,10),'%d/%m/%Y'),'%d/%m/%Y')<=
'07/10/2012';
```

I have converted `varchar` to string in query but my query return query data only related to 29/09/2012 and 30/09/2012. It should also return query for the month of October

Comment: see my answer below. did my solution worked?

Answer (score 8):

Try with this. You can input date in dd/mm/yyyy format as in your question...

```
SELECT * FROM activity_emp
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(server_date_time, '%d/%m/%Y')
  BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('29/08/2012', '%d/%m/%Y')
    AND STR_TO_DATE('07/10/2012', '%d/%m/%Y')
```

**Update:** I strongly recommend you to change datatype from `VARCHAR` to `DATETIME`

Cheers!!!

Comment: This solution should work; but I strongly recommend you to change datatype from VARCHAR to DATETIME...

Comment: This worked like a charm. I'm working on another person database and when I saw varchar it was like...omg. But StackOverflow helped as always.

Answer (score 1):

`STR_TO_DATE` is enough. `DATE_FORMAT` changes it back to `VARCHAR`

```
SELECT...
FROM...
WHERE str_to_date(substr(server_date_time,1,10),'%d/%m/%Y') 
         BETWEEN '29/09/2012' AND '07/10/2012'
```

when dealing `date` please use `DATE` or `DATETIME` data type. This will avoid you from doing casting which affects the performance of the query.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
SELECT * FROM activity_emp
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(server_date_time, '%d/%m/%Y')
  BETWEEN '2012-09-29' AND '2012-09-30'
```

But it is better to store `server_date_time` in DATETIME data type so that MySQL can use index.

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing the dates always in `dd/mm/yyyy` in the column then this is an easy task:

```
SELECT * from activity_emp 
where server_date_time BETWEEN '29/09/2012' AND '07/10/2012'
```

Isn't this enough? Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `activity_emp` 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(  `column_name` ,  '%d/%m/%Y' ) 
BETWEEN  '2010-10-10'
AND  '2010-11-10'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Simple and Easy to understand Date Query to search between Two Dates

```
Date that stored in datebase in like 01/01/2016 and datatype is varchar
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`test`.`date`, '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-31' ORDER BY `test`.`date` ASC
```