# Compare Dates using Between with Column Type VARCHAR

Tags: mysql

I have a database table called `UPDATES` that has some logs inserted to. In this table, there is a column called `Time`. This time column is of type `VARCHAR`. I had no choice but to make it `VARCHAR` because there are updates with corrupt time like, 2013-04-04 00xcdww and sometimes like 2013-4-2 with some non ASCII values. So if the Column type was DATETIME, the insertions of that datetime couldve triggered an error.

Now i am in the phase of doing a comparison between two dates to get range of results.

So my question is, will using a VARCHAR compare the dates correctly ?

doing :

```
Date(Time) BETWEEN 2013-03-02 AND 2013-03-02
```

Or will this return invalid results ? if it does can you tell me what this query will return that is not within the range specified ?

Comment: `2013-03-02` is not a date. It will be treated as a number meaning `2013` minus `3` minus `2`. So your expression evaluates to `Date(time) between 2008 and 2008`. If at all you want `'2013-03-02'` - or more standard compliant `date '2013-03-02'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need to convert the varchar to date format using [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(Time, '%Y-%m-%d')
BETWEEN '2013-03-02' AND '2013-03-02'


mysql> select STR_TO_DATE('2013-04-04 00xcdww', '%Y-%m-%d') ;
+-----------------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('2013-04-04 00xcdww', '%Y-%m-%d') |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| 2013-04-04                                    |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

**STR_TO_DATE** is not enough you have to use **SUBSTR** function to get first **10 VARCHAR**.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `TABLE_NAME` 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(substr(`Time`,1,10),  '%d/%m/%Y' ) 
BETWEEN  '2013-03-02'
AND  '2013-03-02'
```

This will avoid you from doing casting which affects the performance of the query.

---

***Updated***
As your database column may be 2013-04-04 00xcdww and sometimes like 2013-4-2 so you should use this query,

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `TABLE_NAME` 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`Time`, '%d/%m/%Y') 
BETWEEN  '2013-03-02'
AND  '2013-03-02'
```

Comment: This will fail for `select STR_TO_DATE(substr('2013-4-2 xyz',1,10),  '%d/%m/%Y' ) ;`

Comment: never come this format. 2013-04-02 is this right format.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12776075/searching-data-between-dates-stored-in-varchar-in-mysql

Comment: Yes I know its not correct but he is storing as "2013-04-04 00xcdww and sometimes like 2013-4-2 with some non ASCII values"

Comment: @jamil absolutely and i already marked as a duplicate to close this question. but still this time helping to OP's question. OP's not find this link so direct put link its not valid marked as spam link. so its better to explain. Thank you for commeting

Comment: @user1153551: Your solution fails for `2013-4-2` type varchar inputs. Abhik is right. `substring` is not a solution for such inputs.

Comment: depend on questioner database.

Comment: @user1153551: OP already have posted that his database has such data. *`there are updates with corrupt time like, 2013-04-04 00xcdww and sometimes like 2013-4-2`*

Comment: ok thank you for alert me, I remove that substr.. now anything else could i favor for you?