# Retrieve rows with joining date less than 15 days from today

Tags: mysql, sql

Mysql query is

```
SELECT 
    userid as uid, 
    CONCAT( firstname, ' ', lastname ) AS name,
    profileimage,
    joining_date, 
    role as designation
FROM pr_users_details
INNER JOIN pr_users ON pr_users.id = pr_users_details.userid
LEFT JOIN pr_userroles ON pr_userroles.id = pr_users.userroleid
WHERE joining_date > DATE_SUB( NOW()-1 , INTERVAL 15 DAY )
ORDER BY pr_users_details.id DESC
```

I am getting these results which are a year old. I want to display new hires , i.e todays date - 15 days. Am i missing something.

[image]

Comment: What is the type of the `joining_date` column ?

Comment: joining_date seems to be a DATE type column, but NOW() give you a DATE_TIME result

Comment: joining_date varchar(20) utf8_general_ci

Comment: Possible duplicate of [searching data between dates stored in varchar in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12776075/searching-data-between-dates-stored-in-varchar-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store date/times as date times, not strings.  For the comparison to work, you need to convert the value to a string:

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(joining_date, '%d-%m-%Y') > DATE_SUB( NOW()-1 , INTERVAL 15 DAY )
```

However, you should fix the data:

```
update ?  -- whatever the table is
    set joining_date = STR_TO_DATE(joining_date, '%d-%m-%Y');  -- this will convert the date to a canonical format

alter table t alter column joining_date date;
```